# Reversing a .LIB file

Tags: libraries

So I found an mp3 player the other day and I thought it'd be fun to try and reverse engineer the files I found on it (and maybe even try to modify it). When I plugged it in to my pc I was surprised to see more than just folders with mp3 files, I could see a few .LIB files named "AUDIBLE.LIB", "EBOOK.LIB", "M3U.LIB", "MUSIC.LIB", "MUSIC2.LIB", "PICTURE.LIB", "VIDEO.LIB". I wanted to see what they looked like so I tried to find out how to read .LIB files using google, however I did not succeed. I tried dumpbin, hxd and ida, but none of them worked (dumpbin said it was an invalid file format, hxd didn't help with finding a magic number and ida couldn't open it). Each file starts with the name of the file (eg: "PICTURE"), followed by some 00 bytes, the 8th byte is 01 and then come another 5 00 bytes followed by "ALLFILE". I'm new to reverse engineering so I'm sorry if this question is stupid, but how would I go about reverse engineering this?

File example (only the first few lines of bytes):

```
45 42 4F 4F 4B 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
41 4C 4C 46 49 4C 45 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 02 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

In case it matters, the mp3 player is a Xemio-240.

Comment: I have a set of Bluetooth ear buds (Axloie S7) that have a GB of storage built in and also function as an mp3 player. There is a file that stays exactly 1,500KB no matter what I put on the drive titled “MUSIC.LIB” in the root of the drive. I will try to describe how it. Here is the first little chunk, minus the asterisks *MUSIC ALLSONG ALBUM ARTIST GENRE
* Then a bunch of zeros Then metadata for each song with zeros in between Then a bunch of random characters that look like code or encrypted data Then
*UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUULAME3.89 (beta)UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Answer (score 2):

I guess the files you found are *index files*. They contain the list of all pictures, ebooks, playlists (m3u) and so on, so the player doesn't have to open each individual file when you search for a specific song or video.
This means these files are most like a custom database format. The first header line might be something like the "database name", and the second header line, always "ALLFILES" might be a "table name".

I don't recognize this file as the storage format of a well-known open-source database engine, but that would be the area where I suggest you to start researching. It might be a completely custom format, though.

Answer (score 0):

My BT-Voice-Recorder **DVR-188** has also these files:
**Device-Memory**:

```
 AH        384.000 AUDIBLE.LIB
 AH        384.000 EBOOK.LIB
 AH      1.485.312 M3U.LIB
 AH      1.536.000 MUSIC.LIB
 AH        384.000 PICTURE.LIB
 AH        384.000 VIDEO.LIB
   D               RECORD\
                   \A\
                    \REC001.WAV
                   \B
                   \C
                   \D
                    \REC001.MP3
                    \REC002.WAV
```

**TF** (SD-Card):

```
 AH        384.000 AUDIBLE.LIB
 AH        384.000 EBOOK.LIB
 AH      1.485.312 M3U.LIB
 AH      1.536.000 MUSIC.LIB
 A           5.632 MUSICBMK.BMK
 AH        384.000 PICTURE.LIB
 AH         26.624 USERPL1.PL
 AH         26.624 USERPL2.PL
 AH         26.624 USERPL3.PL
 AH        384.000 VIDEO.LIB  
   <DIR>          MUSIC\
                   … *.mp3
                   … *.wav
                   … *.wma
   <DIR>          RECORD\
```

I'm not sure if it can also play FLAC or APE.
Do you need hex-Code?