# Source code for an mp3 player?

Tags: binary-diagnosis, binary-editing, unknown-data

I know this title sounds a little dumb but if you would please bear with me for an explanation. I have a Valoin-made mp3 player I bought close to 3 years ago now. Via a series of interesting discoveries, I have become infatuated with this thing. It plays video (to a degree), the file manager has some oddly specific quirks, the 'home screen' looks eerily like every mp3 player 'home screen' I see on the market, and most importantly, whenever I use an SD card with the device, it offloads some weird files with a format I don't recognize. [In another post I read](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29253/reversing-a-lib-file) a user mentions a similar situation. They seem to have a bunch of .LIB and .PL files added to the root of the SD card file system (FAT32?). Among these files were noticeably: M3U.LIB and EBOOK.LIB. USERPL1.PL, USERPL2.PL, and USERPL3.PL are files native only to my device, it would seem.

I would like to believe that somewhere out there exists a way to interact with the data in these files and maybe understand the weird file-manager quirks. I mentioned that the 'home screen' looks awfully generic and I believe that's for a reason. I think that a company serving as a really niche software vendor might be the common denominator here. If there exists source code that powers these little gizmos, I want to find it. No short of possibly making some phone calls, or digital snooping. If I can't find the source code, I would settle for understanding these .LIB files. If you are curious and/or have the expertise please check out my [github repo](https://github.com/mllegoman/MP3.LIB) that contains the unmodified .LIB files from my mp3 player alongside some pertinent information.

Comment: I think my comment is not an answer so I will put it here. For example, if I use `python -m binwalk -B PICTURE.LIB --dd=".*"` with your `PICTURE.LIB` in your repo, it will give out many readable pictures, I don't know what the picture is about, it seems that it's some game's screenshots?

Comment: Anyway I will try putting the picture in an issue in your repo.

Comment: The same thing can be done for `BOOK.LIB`, which also gives out many pictures, some of them are the same as the pictures from `PICTURE.LIB`

Comment: Also for `M3U.LIB`, so I think those are some frames from a video